# Applescript Compact Calculator Script Issues

Tags: applescript, calculator

I am making a simple, compact calculator script in applescript. I know what the problem is, but I don't know if it is possible to fix it. When I run the script and input the numbers, it just says the equation back to me. I expected it to do this, but is there a way for it to do the math?

```
set theMultiply to text returned of (display dialog "What is the problem?" default answer "# * #" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2)
set theAnswer to theMultiply
display dialog theAnswer buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2
```

Comment: By programming it to do the math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the math using "run script":

```
set theMultiply to text returned of (display dialog "What is the problem?" default answer "# * #" buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 2)
set theAnswer to run script theMultiply
display dialog theAnswer
```

With run script, you aren't locked into just multiply either. Any mathematical sequence will be evaluated as such.

Comment: Except that can be dangerous

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to have two dialogs display, prompting for a number each, and then multiply the two numbers to form a result. This is the code I have come up with to do this:

```
set term1 to getNewTerm("Enter the first number to be multiplied")
set term2 to getNewTerm("Enter the second number to be multiplied")
set answer to term1 * term2
display dialog (term1 as string) & " * " & (term2 as string) & " is " & (answer as string)


on getNewTerm(message)
    set numError to missing value
    repeat until numError is false
        try
            set newTerm to text returned of (display dialog message default answer "") as number
            set numError to false
        on error
            display dialog "Please enter a number"
            set numError to true
        end try
    end repeat
    return newTerm
end getNewTerm
```

Hope this helps...